# Retargeting in Fb,Google

Tags: facebook, adsense, pixel

I have a campaign and pixel Id for Fb and Google both which looks something like this.

Can some one tell me how can I implement retargeting pixel in FB, google. What are the changes do I need to make in this dynamicaly generated Pixel script?

```
PixelScript = PixelScript + "<script>(function(){" + Environment.NewLine +
              "window._fbds = window._fbds || {};" + Environment.NewLine +
              "_fbds.pixelId = " + FB_Pixel + ";" + Environment.NewLine +
              "var fbds = document.createElement(\"script\");" + Environment.NewLine +
              "fbds.async = true;" + Environment.NewLine +
              "fbds.src = \"//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js\";" + Environment.NewLine +
              "var s = document.getElementsByTagName(\"script\")[0];" + Environment.NewLine +
              "s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);" + Environment.NewLine +
              "})();" + Environment.NewLine +
              "window._fbq = window._fbq || [];" + Environment.NewLine +
              "window._fbq.push([\"track\", \"PixelInitialized\", {}]);" + Environment.NewLine +
              "</script>" + Environment.NewLine +
              "<noscript><img height=\"1\" width=\"1\" border=\"0\" alt=\"\" style=\"display:none\" src=\"https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=" + FB_Pixel + "&amp;ev=NoScript\" /></noscript>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given pixel is enough to drop cookies on the website. No need to add anything.